# Themeforest Admin Dashboard Template in ASP.NET application

Tags: php, html, asp.net, responsive-design, themes

I have come across few admin templates in themeforest.net such as [Metronic](http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469). But when I checked almost every template is using some PHP for server side coding.

I want to know if these templates works with ASP.NET web application without any sorts of issues. Has anyone tried this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will work with any language - personally i am using templates from this site https://wrapbootstrap.com . You can safely delete all the PHP code and substitute it with your c# asp.net code.

Comment: I saw one sample where a lot of PHP code is involved in the highly interactive UI creation. (Lot of dynamic data are populated from PHP using AJAX). So I really doubt if I remove them, whether it will work properly. (Maybe I need to write all the corresponding C# code)

Answer (score -1):

Surely, it works with any backend. We are using Metronic with ASP.NET MVC.
We have also a commerical product which uses Metronic as UI and provides pre-built admin panel functionality: http://www.aspnetzero.com/